# Passing distance matrix to k-means clustering in sklearn

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

As per as the [sklearn kmeans documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), it says that k-means requires a matrix of shape=(n_samples, n_features). But I provided a distance matrix of shape=(n_samples,n_samples) where each index holds the distance between two strings. The time series has been converted into strings using the [SAX](https://jmotif.github.io/sax-vsm_site/morea/algorithm/SAX.html) representation.

When I ran the clustering with the distance matrix, it gives good result. What can be the possible reason for this? As far as I know, K-medoids is the one which works with distance matrix.

Answer (score 6):

K-means, as the name indicates, uses *means*.

Computing the arithmetic mean requires access to the original features, a distance matrix cannot be used.

K-means also **does not use pairwise distances**. So the distance matrix is useless for this algorithm.

Choose a different algorithm instead, such as hierarchical clustering.

Comment: What algorithm supports this?