# Find the distance between each element and the centroid based on distance matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, k-means, distance-matrix

I have a distance matrix (pairwise distance between elements) and I would like to find the centroid of the set and get the distance between each element and the centroid.

I was trying to use k-means to do it and set the `n_clusters=1`

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=1)
km.fit(distance_matrix)
km.cluster_centers_
```

The `cluster_centers_` returns a list of coordinates but I'm not sure if that represents the distance between each element and the centroid.

If k-means is not the correct way for this problem, which algorithm shall I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing distance matrix to k-means clustering in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512808/passing-distance-matrix-to-k-means-clustering-in-sklearn)

Comment: Also related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/perform-k-means-or-its-close-kin-clustering-with-only-a-distance-matrix-not-p

Comment: Yes, so it looks kernel k-means is the better solution? I'm still not 100% sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

K-Means does not use pairwise distances. So the distance matrix is useless for this algorithm.
K-Means accepts a 2D or more data samples. Define your features(dimensions) for your data set and provide data accordingly, construct the matrix, then pass the matrix into the K-Means as you did above.

`km.cluster_centers_` will return you the list of centroids then.

You need at least some reference ground to calculate the centroid, at least the co-ordinates of the points. Then you can even use the k-means to calculate the centroids in various clusters. Then you can calculate the distance of each point from centroid. Distance matrix is useless here if no co-ordinate between the points are given.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To obtain the centers of the clusters
centroids = km.cluster_centers_
```

Assume dataset is a dataframe (m*n dimension).

```
# distances 
distances = np.empty((0,len(dataset.axes[0])), float)

# getting points and distances
for i, center_elem in enumerate(centroids):
    print(len(center_elem))
    # cdist is used to calculate the distance between center and other points
    distances = np.append(distances, cdist([center_elem],dataset[clusters == i],'euclidean'))
```

So, now the distances have the distance between the point and corresponding centroid.